# CodeSignal hidden test case failing - FareEstimator

Tags: go, testing

One single hidden test case is continuing to fail, leaving me unknowing on where the fault is in the code. From what I've derived from the function-input restrictions, there should be no special test cases; however, maybe that's the case. All other test cases succeed. Here is the CodeFights description of the problem:

> Uber is building a Fare Estimator that can tell you how much your ride will cost before you request it. It works by passing approximated ride distance and ride time through this formula:
>
> (Cost per minute) * (ride time) + (Cost per mile) * (ride distance)
>
> where Cost per minute and Cost per mile depend on the car type.
>
> You are one of the engineers building the Fare Estimator, so knowing cost per minute and cost per mile for each car type, as well as ride distance and ride time, return the fare estimates for all car types.

Here are the constraints for the inputs:

> 10 ≤ **ride_time** ≤ 50
>
> 5 ≤ **ride_distance** ≤ 20
>
> 4 ≤ **cost_per_minute.length** ≤ 10
>
> 0.1 ≤ **cost_per_minute[i]** ≤ 350.0
>
> **cost_per_mile.length** = **cost_per_minute.length**
>
> 0.5 ≤ **cost_per_mile[i]** ≤ 7.0

This is for CodeSignal, for a question that seemed easy at first glance. I tried replicating my code in JavaScript and all of the test cases passed there. The only real difference I can see is the conversion from int to float32 in Go (even though JavaScript does this behind the scenes). Thus, I tried to convert the integers and float32:s to float64:s before doing the arithmetic, in belief that there could've been a (very unlikely) fault in that there weren't enough decimals. None of it worked. I also tried to use append(ans, *allofthatstuff*) but nothing changed.

Go (code in question)

```golang
func fareEstimator(ride_time int, ride_distance int, cost_per_minute []float32, cost_per_mile []float32) []float32 {
    ans := make([]float32, len(cost_per_mile))
    // ans := []float32{}

    for i := 0; i < len(cost_per_mile); i++ {
        ans[i] = cost_per_minute[i] * float32(ride_time) + cost_per_mile[i] * float32(ride_distance)
        // ans = append(ans, cost_per_minute[i] * float32(ride_time) + cost_per_mile[i] * float32(ride_distance))
    }

    return ans
}
```

JavaScript

```
function fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile) {
  var ans = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < cost_per_mile.length; i++) {
    ans.push(cost_per_minute[i] * ride_time + cost_per_mile[i] * ride_distance);
  }

  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Can you give the output for a particular case where the JS and Go versions are different?

Comment: @jesse No, sorry. Because it is for the website codesignal the output (and input) for that test case is hidden.